# Получить список друзей в facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-api

Я делаю приложение которое должно получать список друзей у пользователя в Facebook. Я усиленно гуглил, и не нашел ничего стоящего. Например метод "me/friends" возвращает только общее число друзей без какой либо информации о них. Оказалось что он может вернуть информацию только о друзьях, которые используют приложение.

---

Чем то похожим на нужное поведение обладает метод /me/taggable_friends. Но он возвращает idшники в виде который нельзя использовать для получения более детальной информации о контакте.

---

Возможно я что то пропустил, так что буду рад любой подсказке.

---

Дополнение. invitable_friends возвращает список вроде taggable_friends и не подходит по тем же причинам.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте `/me/invitable_friends`

Comment: Увы но получить id пользователей для загрузки более детальной информации о контакте используя метод /me/invitable_friends невозможно. Проблема схожа с /me/taggable_friends. Но спасибо за ответ.